# Multiple GIT repositories in a workspace

Tags: ros, github, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear fellow ROS-users,

I was wondering about the best practice to maintain multiple GIT repositories within a workspace (and possibly another GIT-repository). This problem is also present when forking repositories of GitHub for instance.

We have a current set-up:

- Four workspaces.
- One big repository containing all packages we have created, containing all the workspaces.

What we want:

- Different repositories for different (groups of) packages.
- Automatic updates (git pull) of repositories.

I have taken a look at GIT submodules. But in my opinion it is quite unclear when working on these.
For instance:

- On what repository am I working (committing/pushing/pulling) at the moment? This results in commits done on wrong repositories. Adding a folder of a submodule when adding on its parent result in the folder added to the parent GIT repository.

Is was wondering how other people are doing this. Second, what are your thoughts on the best way to do this and also having all the GIT repositories up-to-date?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198807/multiple-git-repositories-in-a-workspace/) by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/wstool is exactly what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on 2014-12-03**:
It works like a charm. Thank you for your quick comment on this issue!